# Is there a more Pythonic way to create a Series with memory

Tags: python, python-3.x

This takes a `numpy.array` and returns a `pandas.Series`.

Is there a more Pythonic way of writing this rather then a `for` loop with `if`s?

```
def channel_memory(elements, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    signal = 0;
    signals = [];
    for element in elements:
        if element is np.nan:
            pass
        elif signal != 1 and element >= upper_bound:
            signal = 1
        elif signal != -1 and element <= lower_bound:
            signal = -1
        signals.append(signal)

    return pd.Series(signals)
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that some checks are not so necessary. If the element is `np.nan` - none of the comparisons will be true so the previous value will be kept. Same goes for the checks of `signal != +/-1` - if the `signal` is `1` and the new element is greater than the bound, nothing will change. So one way to "improve" the code can be:

```py
def channel_memory(elements, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    signal = 0
    signals = []
    for element in elements:
        if element >= upper_bound:
            signal = 1
        elif element <= lower_bound:
            signal = -1
        signals.append(signal)

    return pd.Series(signals)
```

The following alternative way might be longer in code-length but I feel it conveys more clearly what happens in the code with the use of iterators. First we add `0`s as long as the number is between the bounds. Once it left the bounds, we keep adding the same value until there is a change in bound, until the iterator on the list is exhausted:

```py
def channel_memory(elements, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    signals = []
    elements = iter(elements)
    element = next(elements)
    while lower_bound < element < upper_bound:
        signals.append(0)
        element = next(elements)

    while True:
        try:
            while element > lower_bound:
                signals.append(1)
                element = next(elements)

            while element < upper_bound:
                signals.append(-1)
                element = next(elements)
        except StopIteration:
            break

    return pd.Series(signals)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the simplifications that were proposed by Tomerikoo, I would suggest to use a generator function to `yield` the signal values.

Then you don't need a temporary list, and moreover, I would consider this Pythonic :-)

```py
def channel_memory(elements, lower_bound, upper_bound):

    def signals():
        signal =  0
        for element in elements:
            if element >= upper_bound:
                signal = 1
            elif element <= lower_bound:
                signal = -1
            yield signal
    
    return pd.Series(signals())
```

Comment: Do you think this will be faster than Tomerikoo's first answer? Tomerikoo's first answer seems (to me) to be the most readable.

Comment: I haven't tested which approach is faster. The generator solution doesn't need a temporary list and thus saves memory allocations, which also need time. On the other hand, the management of the generator might add some overhead. You would have to try it with a suitable benchmark :-)

Comment: BTW, I see that the list-based solution may look more readable if you are not familiar with generators and the `yield` keyword. I was in the same situation myself some years ago. But generators are used a lot in Python and allow you to do many things, such as construct iterables which wouldn't fit in memory as a temporary list, or even infinite iterables. Therefore, I would recommend every Python programmer to make themselves familiar with the `yield` keyword :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using pandas already, why not utilize it to its fullest?

```
def channel_memory(elements, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    return pd.Series(elements).fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(0).clip(lower = lower_bound, upper = upper_bound)
```

P.S. This seems most pythonic to me as well.

### How does this work?

`fillna(method = 'ffill')` keeps filling nan values with the last non-nan value it encountered. So caters the memory part of your logic. `fillna(0)` then fills any number of leading `nan` values with zeros (what you used as your initial signal value. This can of course be any value). `.clip()` then clips all values to range `(1,-1)`. Which effectively emulates:

Start a signal with `0`, till a non-nan value encounters. then starts filling with values ranging in (-1, 1) based on threshold. Eventually translating to your logic.

Comment: Does this just 'clip' the upper and lower values? How does this keep a memory of previous signal value?

Comment: Updated! `fillna()` paired with this is what you are looking for to keep a memory of previous signal value.

Comment: I think fillna() is just fills NaN values, I don't think it is quite what my logic does. Please explain further if you think it does